# How to run nuxt dev on a production server

Tags: nuxt.js, pm2, nginx-reverse-proxy

I'm using Nuxt 2.15.4 and I have deployed my app on a cloud-server using nginx and pm2.

I can access my website by using its domain address. Now I want to use `npm run dev` on another post on my server for development beside the main running website. For example `https://example.com:3333` show me the dev (live) mode so that I can see changes live.

How can I do that??

Comment: Isn't your deployed Nuxt remote ? You should have no trouble running a local `dev` server. Meanwhile, if you want to have both local, I'm interested too, since `dev` or `build` are overriding each other's.

Comment: Actually It has no problem in local! you can `run dev` and `run build` in two terminal and it will do both on different ports. what I want is both on server so I can do development on server! (the reason is, sometimes what I see on local is diff from what is deployed on server, and also I have my app on multiple servers and sometimes there is need to do development on one of them)

Comment: Actually `nuxt start` is using a built version located in `/dist` but it is also creating a `.nuxt` directory. `nuxt dev` is also creating a `.nuxt` directory. But I guess that the `.nuxt`'s production directory is just for cache/performance at this point and that only `/dist` matters. But I rather respect the order of `nuxt build` >> `nuxt start` >> `nuxt dev` to avoid any issues since `/dist` is created at the end.

Comment: Hi, did my answer helped somehow ?

Comment: well, it kinda helped me to give up! :D . At least without use of reverse proxy on dev port too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What do you mean by "development on one of them"? Should should probably not change your code based on some handmade changes, that will not be tracked by git. How are you supposing to find bugs if you do untracked changes like this?

And also, I'm not sure what requires that kind of workflow?

If you have an issue on your production environment, you should fix it locally and deploy it there by knowing what are the specific differences in production.

For your question, depending if PM2 is able to run a project with a Node.js server (I guess) it could and that you can access it with SSH (maybe you cannot), you could basically do this:

- run a dev server on a specific port
- connect via SSH to that specific server and make on the fly-changes
- wait 5 hours for the page too refresh (not a bundled build so yeah, dev server will take ages to update the changes...)

Still, it's super ugly to "make changes" like this. To understand what is buggy may be a viable use case but you could at this point, dump the production database into local or reproduce the behavior of the production locally. Anyway, I do highly **not** recommend this idea of running a dev server on production.

Comment: I understand what you mean, and believe so too. It was mentioned in a meeting and I got curious so tried and my resources like fonts, js files and images all got 404; probably because of reverse proxy. so i just wanted to know that is it possible to have two running nuxt app on one server , one in production mode and the other dev mode or not. BTW tanx

Comment: You could do that but it requires more configuration and it's far from being the recommended way (performance, security, errors, bugs). What would be the use case for this?